# Trying to append UTF-8(Celsius sign)

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(".tempe").append( (  ((json.main.temp-32)*5)/(9)) + " &#8451 " );
```

So,I am trying to append the above but I get the following output:
147.9388888888889 &#8451

&#8451 corresponds to the Celcius sign(UTF-8).Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `&#8451;` (semicolon was missing).

Here is an example:

```js
$(".tempe").append(  12345 + " &#8451; " );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tempe"></div>
```